# Как получить ссылку на отправителя сигнала в методе?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt

Есть несколько `QLineEdit`: `lineEdit1` и `lineEdit2`, по сигналу `textEdited` вызывается некоторый метод `method_2`.

Что я должен сделать, чтобы в методе `method_2` `object` являлся сначала `lineEdit1`, потом `lineEdit2`?

```
...
def method_1(self):
    self.lineEdit1.textEdited.connect(self.method_2)
    self.lineEdit2.textEdited.connect(self.method_2)

def method_2(self):
    if len(object.text()) > 0:
        print('OK')
...
```

Comment: Как вариант, если я правильно понял Вас, можно изменить определение method_2(self) на method_2(self, some_text_edit) и внутри делать some_text_edit.setText('blabla'), а при вызове метода при возбуждении сигнала для передачи параметра использовать безымянную функцию: self.lineEdit1.textEdited.connect(lambda: self.method_2(self.lineEdit1)) и аналогично self.lineEdit2.textEdited.connect(lambda: self.method_2(self.lineEdit2))

Comment: Cигнал `QLineEdit.textEdited(text)` излучается всякий раз, когда текст редактируется, 
т.е. изменяется иначе, чем при вызове `setText()`.
Этот сигнал не выдается, когда текст изменяется программно, например, вызывая `setText()`.
Вы не можете одновременно набирать текст в `lineEdit1` и `lineEdit2`.
Какой `lineEdit{1|2}` вы редактируете, тот `lineEdit{1|2}` и будет излучать сигнал и вызывать метод `method_2`. 
Уточните пожалуйста свой вопрос.

Comment: @Anton, да, вы меня правильно поняли, вариант с lambda подходит! Спасибо за помощь!   А существуют другие способы выполнить эту задачу? Можно просто тему, которую я должен изучить для этого. Для общего развития, так сказать :)

Comment: @johnzet, можно вызвать метод `self.sender()` чтобы получить объект, чей сигнал вызвал данный метод: `self.sender().setText("123")`

Comment: @gil9red, отлично! Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать метод [self.sender()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) – для получения объекта, чей сигнал вызвал текущий метод.

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QWidget, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QApplication


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.le_1 = QLineEdit('123')
        self.le_1.textEdited.connect(self._method_1)

        self.le_2 = QLineEdit('abc')
        self.le_2.textEdited.connect(self._method_1)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.le_1)
        layout.addWidget(self.le_2)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def _method_1(self, text):
        print(self.sender(), text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    
    mw = Widget()
    mw.show()
    
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Да, а это то, что надо. Я self.sender() неправильно ранее использовал. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант. Не обязательно использовать метод self.sender().

Из документации `QObject *QObject::sender() const`:
...

> Предупреждение: эта функция нарушает объектно-ориентированный принцип модульности. Однако получение доступа к отправителю может быть полезно, когда многие сигналы подключены к одному слоту.
>   ...

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QWidget, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QApplication

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.le_1 = QLineEdit('123')
        self.le_1.textEdited[str].connect(self._method_1)   # <--- [str]

        self.le_2 = QLineEdit('abc')
        self.le_2.textEdited[str].connect(self._method_1)   # <--- [str]  

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.le_1)
        layout.addWidget(self.le_2)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def _method_1(self, text):
        print(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = Widget()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```